# When creating a new line in a grid, is there a way to have it create at the bottom instead of the middle of the grid?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

Is there a way during record creation (Ctrl+N) to have the line be created automatically at the end of the grid instead of right in the middle?

I know this is just visually where it creates it, but it still creates some confusion.

This is what I've done so far on the datasource, but it's not working right:

```
public void create(boolean _append = false)
{
    this.setPosition(MyTable.RowCount());

    super(_append);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah figured it out.  Just had to check MSDN.

```
public void create(boolean _append = true)
{
    this.last();
    super(_append);
}
```

Comment: I usually think it's best practice to emphasize when overloading that the defaults are being overridden for the purpose of upgrades.  I can't tell you how many times I've seen a code migration/merge and missed changes to the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In my testing if the grid already has lines, the new line always before the last existing line. The added line is the last-second line, cannot be the last one.